# My "not connected" TCP Client is connected?

Tags: delphi, indy10

Given the following code, which is the first code having anything to do with my `TIdTCPClient` when my program runs

```
try
  if not TCPclient.Connected then
  begin
     TraceInfo(TCPclient.Host + ' Server not connected - reconnect');
     TCPclient.Connect();

     TCPclient.GetResponse(200);
     ConnectedToServer();
     TraceInfo(TCPclient.Host + ' Connect OK');
  end;

except   // when trying to connect to server
    on EIdAlreadyConnected : Exception do
    begin
       TraceWarning(TCPclient.Host + ' Attempt to Connect when already connected');
    end
    else    // Failed to connect for any other reason
    begin
       TraceError(TCPclient.Host + ' Connect FAILED !!!!');
       Exit; 
    end;
end;

// we either connected or noticed that we were already connected
try
  resultCode := TCPclient.SendCmd(theMessage);
  if resultCode = 200 then
  begin
     TraceInfo(TCPclient.Host + ' Sent OK');
     Result := TCPclient.LastCmdResult.Text.Text;
     DisconnectFromServer(TCPclient);
     Exit;
  end
  else
  begin
     TraceWarning(TCPclient.Host + ' Send rejected by server (result code = ' + IntToStr(resultCode) + ') !!!!');
      DisconnectFromServer(TCPclient);
      Exit;
  end;

except
  on E : Exception do       // EIdNotConnected
  begin
     Result := '';
     TraceError(TCPclient.Host + ' Send FAILED (exception "' + E.ClassName + '")');
  end;
```

end;

I cannot understand why the trace log says

```
00:00:00 [10.21.18.211 Server not connected - reconnect]    12:21:38 PM
00:00:01 [10.21.18.211 Attempt to Connect when already connected]   12:21:40 PM
00:00:01 [10.21.18.211 FAILED to connect to server] 12:21:40 PM
00:00:01 [10.21.18.211 Send FAILED (exception "EIdNotConnected")]   12:21:40 PM
```

Can anyone see somthing obviously wrong with my code? Or can I provide more information to help you to help me?

Thanks in advance

---

Update, for clarification:

How can we have

if not TCPclient.Connected then
  begin
     TraceInfo(TCPclient.Host + ' Server not connected - reconnect');

and then

```
 TraceError(TCPclient.Host + ' Send FAILED (exception "' + E.ClassName + '")');
```

Comment: (Re-)entrancy to this code from multiple threads?

Comment: Threading would make it more likely, but re-entrancy may still be happening. For example from ConnectedToServer (as Sean also suggests in his answer). On the other hand, that would mainly explain the first two trace messages, not necessarily the last two. I'd put in more tracing, even going so far as around each statement. I'd add result of GetCurrentThreadId to the trace messages to ensure threading is not an issue. And I'd use madExcept or some such to add stacktraces to at least the exception messages, possibly to all trace messages (with madExcept you can request a stacktrace at any time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, `Connected()` performs a reading operation to determine socket state.  If the `IOHandler.InputBuffer` is not empty, even if the socket is physically disconnected, `Connected()` will return True.  `Connect()` calls `Connected()` internally and raises the `EIdAlreadyConnected` exception if `Connected()` return True, so it may be possible that your first call to `Connected()` is receiving new data that is causing the second call to `Connected()` to return True.

Comment: +1 Thanks, @Remy. In fact, I was calling the dsiconnect code shown above before connecting. Would that obviate this potential problem? (I never caught a EIdAleadyConnected, btw)

Comment: `Disconnect()` does not clear the `IOHandler.InputBuffer`, so if you close the socket without reading everything that has been received and buffered, such as when reacting to an error, `Connected()` will continue returning True. You usually need to call `IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear()` after calling `Disconnect()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have not supplied a listing for the ConnectedToServer() procedure/method. If this procedure makes an attempt to connect the TCPclient object, then this would explain your results.

Comment: +1 Sorry, I ought to have removed that. It simply updates the status bar